# Python: Modifying one attribute to each object in a list

Tags: python, list, oop, iteration

My question is basic and is maybe a duplicate but I haven't found the answer.

I am looking for the most efficient (pythonic) way of adding 1 to the attribute `x` of all objects of a given list.

```
class Any(object):
   def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x

l = [Any(1), Any(-3), Any(1), Any(4), Any(6), Any(7), Any(3)]
```

Is there a better solution than (using list comprehension for example):

```
for i in l:
    i.x += 1
```

Comment: Your way is perfectly pythonic.

Comment: Ha ha OK ! Coming from R, I got used to be affraid of `for` loops! I guess, you can write your comment as an answer. Thank you

Comment: Typically, you should avoid using list comprehensions when there are side effects (such as modifying an object). Your way is fine. I think writing it any other way would probably be more trouble then it's worth :)

Comment: The for loops is the way to go. The only bad thing here is using `l` as a variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way is perfectly pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code, but if you want to use it in a comprehension, add an "increment" method:

```
def inc(self, amount=1):
    self.x += amount
    return self
```